# when I switch to other window, GoLand will format my code, how to stop that action?

Tags: go, goland

I usually want to copy and paste code from browser or something else when I am writing code.
Here is a case.
I am writing code:

```golang
callSomeFunc(p1, p1, )
```

I left GoLand with a `,` , because I want copy and paste the third param, and as long as I leave GoLand window, the `,`  is gone, I have to type in it again, which make me frustriting.

Do you, my friend, konw how to stop Goland doing that.

Left Goland windows and every code stays the same when I returned.
Format the code only when I Commit it to Git.

Comment: Settings->Tools->Actions On Save->Reformat code.

Comment: Usually: 1. Copy content 2 Go back to where you want to paste. 3. Add commas and paste. 4 Code saving and automatic formatting. Maintaining a good code format during editing is very pleasing to the eye.